# Why I can not simply ssh to docker container from my windows host?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh

I try to ssh from my windows host to a docker ubuntu container. I know, I can use `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash` to launch, however, I want to do a normal "ssh root@192.168.xx.xx" to login because I want to simulate remote computer login and also it works also easily with my pycharm.

However, after I installed "openssh-server", and started it, the login with ssh from my host is still not possible.

```
:~$ ssh root@192.168.99.105

>>> The authenticity of host '192.168.99.105 (192.168.99.105)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:********
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Warning: Permanently added '192.168.99.105' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@192.168.99.105's password: xxx
Permission denied, please try again.
```

How can I solve this problem? I just want to simply ssh to this container...

Comment: you need to configre ssh firstly, I think you should search for allow root login

Comment: Thanks, but do you know where can I config the ssh to allow root login?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: You should think of a Docker container as a wrapper around a single application, and not as something you routinely get an interactive shell in.  How do you ssh to, for example, your Web browser?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze I just simply use the "docker quick start" terminal on my windows.

Comment: @LinPy I changed the configuration and reloaded it, but it still the same...

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question asked in the title:

> Why I can not simply ssh to docker container from my windows host?

Docker is a way to configure Linux kernel settings on a process to limit what the process can see (namespaces) and how many resources that process can use (cgroups). So this question becomes "why can't I ssh into a process" and the answer is typically because that process is not an sshd server. The Ubuntu image for docker is not a virtual machine with all the associated daemons, it doesn't even include the kernel. Instead, it's a minimal filesystem with utilities found in a Ubuntu environment (like `apt-get` and `bash`).

On the other hand, the `docker exec` command does work because it is running a second command in the same isolated environment as the rest of the container. So if `bash` is installed in the image, then `docker exec -it $container_id bash` will run an interactive shell with the same namespaces and cgroups as the rest of your container processes.

If you want to ssh into your container, my advice is that you don't. This is similar to a code smell, a sign you are treating containers like a VM, and will have issues with the immutability and ephemeral nature of containers. The goal of working with containers is to have all your changes pushed into version control, build a new image, and deploy that image, for every change to the production environment. This eliminates the risk of state drift where interactive changes were made over time by one person and not known to the person trying to rebuild the environment later.

If you still prefer to ignore the advice, or your application is explicitly an sshd server, then you need to install and configure sshd as your running application inside of the container. There's [documentation from Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) on how to do this, and lots of examples on Docker Hub from various individuals if you search on sshd (note that I don't believe any of these are official so I wouldn't recommend any of them).

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to configure sshd on the container to allow root access and/or enable password authentication.

```
sudo sed -i 's|[#]*PasswordAuthentication no|PasswordAuthentication yes|g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo PermitRootLogin yes | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service sshd restart
```

One or both of these commands may help if you container image is ubuntu/debian based. I personally have never had the need to ssh into a docker container.

Comment: Hi have you ever tried this on your own windows? I tried it, but it doesn't work...

Comment: I have not tried this from a docker container inside a Windows host but that should not matter. After installing openssh-server you need to configure sshd. If you docker exec into your container, those commands should allow ssh with root user and password authentication. If you are still having issues you could try enabling some logging for the sshd service to get more than "Permission denied, please try again."

Comment: It is really strange, I tried your method and also the docker tutorial which introduced by @BMitch , however, none of them works. I guess, maybe some network problem?